# Android how to track user's action

Tags: android, serialization, tracking

I've got a question more about a strategy to use in order to implement the following requirement.

I need to develop a functionality where a user can perform some actions in the application like posting photos, commenting on photos etc. Every of this actions should leave a log somewhere and after entering one of the screens in my app, all the logs should be visible chronologically (the latest first). I've used a TreeSet sorted by item date and it works pretty fine. The problem is to keep this data persistently so that there's a never ending history of logs. I'm reluctant to migrate my code to SQLite unless it's necessary.. I like quite a lot my TreeSet structure thanks to its methods I managed to keep the logic simple. The problem starts when I'm to save this object across different launches of my app....
Has any one any idea how to solve it? Maybe TreeSet is a wrong decision though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the Logs in SQLite isn't a bad idea. Your other options is to put them in a file, and keep writing to it. You could then write a class to handle sorting it which shouldn't be too bad. The added benefit of using SQLite would be that sorting by Date would be a breeze. But then then exporting it would require the extra work, while having it already in a file makes it easy. So its really just a preference.

Comment: I agree entirely. Your persistent storage options are SQLite, SharedPreferences, cloud, and files on the SDCard. SharedPreferences isn't very good at storing collections, and it sounds like you want to store locally, so cloud is out. Between SQLite and a text file, I would go with SQLite because it offers sorting/querying options that a flat text file doesn't